# Fixed position jQuery waypoint right under first waypoint and not the top

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-waypoints

I want the navigation bar the be fixed position whenever 
it touches the that dark blue rectangle and not when it reaches the 
brower top you can  view what i am after here: http://cuberapp.com/ any 
help appreciated thanks.

```
jQuery('.wrap_head').waypoint('sticky', {
  stuckClass: 'stuck1',
  offset:'bottom-in-view'
});                    

//jQuery('.navbar').waypoint('sticky', {
  // stuckClass: 'stuck1',
   //offset: 99
//});

//initialise Stellar.js
    jQuery(window).stellar();
    //Cache some variables
    var i = 1;
    var nav_container = jQuery(".nav-wrapper");
    var nav = jQuery(".navbar");

    var top_spacing = 99;
    var waypoint_offset = 50;

    var num = jQuery('li.menu-item').find('a').each(function () {
         jQuery(this).attr('data-slide', i);
         i++;
        });   

    mywindow = jQuery(window);
    htmlbody = jQuery('html,body');

    //Setup waypoints plugin    
    nav_container.waypoint(function (direction) {   

            if (direction === 'down') {

                nav_container.css({ 'height':nav.outerHeight() });      
                nav.stop().addClass('stuck').css("top",- nav.outerHeight())
.animate({"top":top_spacing});

            }else {

                nav_container.css({ 'height':'auto' });


nav.stop().removeClass("stuck")
.css("top",nav.outerHeight()+waypoint_offset).animate({"top":""});

            }

    }, {
offset: function() {
        return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') / 3 - nav.outerHeight()-

waypoint_offset;            
        }
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure how the elements on your page are positioned. Some more information would be helpful (Is Cuber an example or the page you are working on?). Still, this may be what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Yks/41/

jQuery

```
function positionMenu(){
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= $('#image').height() - $('#bluebar').height() ) {
        $('#menu').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top' : $('#bluebar').height() + 'px'});
    } else {
        $('#menu').css({'position': 'static'});
    }
}


    positionMenu(); // position once when ready

    $(window).scroll(function () { 
    positionMenu(); // position every time the user scrolls
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="bluebar"></div>
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 100%; }

#bluebar {
    background: navy; 
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; }

#image {
    background: #ddd; 
    height: 300px; }

#menu {
    background: red; 
    height: 80px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your suggestion didn't work .wrap_head is positioned fixed and the .navbar as well. My problem is i don't want the navigation to jump from the top i just want it to stop once it touches that blue bar having hell with this thanks

Comment: Thanks eevaa worked perfectly i have another problem, do you have any experience with wordpress and bootstrap it seem on the site i am working on the bootstrap.js is having a conflict with the contact form 7 plugin the send button won't work. Any ideas and thanks again